# How can I combine two lists by comparing elements in this way?

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm just starting to learn Haskell, and I have to create a function `composite` that receives two lists `a, b :: [(String, String)]` as inputs, and outputs a new list `c :: [(String, String)]`, which is a 'composition' of both `a` and `b`. Specifically, list `c` has to include only those pairs `(p,q)`, where there is a `r` such that:

- `(p,r)` is in `a`
- `(r,q)` in in `b`

For example:

- `composite [("1","2")] [("2","3"), ("2","4")] == [("1","3"), ("1","4")]`
- `composite [("1","2"), ("5","2")] [("2","3"), ("2","4")] == [("1","3"), ("1","4"), ("5","3"), ("5","4")]`
- `composite [("1","2"), ("1","4"), ("1","5")] [("2","3"), ("4","3")] == [("1","3")]`

How can I do this?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that SO is not a write-my-code website. It is expected that you at least present your solution so far, even if incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the lists using a list comprehension over multiple lists:

```
[(x,z)|(x,y) <- a, (y',z) <- b, y == y' ]
```

Note that the result is the list if `(x,z)` tuples, and the inputs are the lists of `(x,y)` and `(y,z)` tuples.

I have tried this in http://tryhaskell.org with your list test case; feel free to copy-paste it there and play around with it:

```
[(x,z) | (x,y) <-[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e')],(y',z) <- [('b','c'), ('d','c')], y == y']
```

This yields:

> [('a','c'),('a','c')]

There are a few other things to note.

First, the `y == y'`. As @chi points out, if you use 'y' again in the list comprehension, the system does not consider it the same variable. You need to use a new variable, `y'` (or any other name) and explicitly tell Haskell that `y` and `y'` should have the same value.

Second, we're not using capitals; Haskell is case-sensitive and uses capitals for other purposes.

Third, you don't have to make it only for Strings. The function can operate on tuples of arbitrary types:

```
composite :: [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
```

As @Daniel Wagner observes in the comments, it's actually a little more complicated:

```
composite :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
```

The `Eq a` tells Haskell that `a` is something that you can compare for equality. Formally, `a` is a member of the `Eq` type class.
He also observes that we can generalize this further: the lefthand side of the tuples in list A don't have to be of the same type as the righthand side of the tuples in list B. So you could have, for example, a list of `(Int,String)` and a list of `(String,Char)`, and match them on the String. The type would become:

```
composite :: Eq b => [(a, b)] -> [(b, c)] -> [(a, c)]
```

A final thing to note is that there may be duplicates in your resulting list. This is the case in your third test case.

The exercise probably doesn't require you to remove the duplicates.. yet.
Haskells libraries provide tools to remove duplicates. In a production setting, you should use these tools. But when learning, writing your own code to remove duplicates may be a useful exercise.

I've also got it in [ideone.org](http://ideone.com/w8buTb). Don't worry about the "main" and "print" over there for now; just experiment with the function and see if you understand it.

Comment: The first example does not work. The second binding for `y` will shadow the first, as if it were `[(x,z) | (,x_) <- a , (y,z) <- b]`

Comment: @chi Looks like you're right :-(  It worked for the first two cases, but doesn't actually unify on `y`. I'll have to update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot from your post. Glad you could help!

Comment: You can't give `composite` the more general type you claim: you need at least an `Eq` constraint. So it has to be more specific in that sense. But it can also be less specific in another sense, since there's no reason to require that all the parts of the tuple be the same type. So a better type would be `composite :: Eq b => [(a, b)] -> [(b, c)] -> [(a, c)]`. This is also the type that will be inferred for you if you don't give a type signature at all.

Answer (score 3):

[S.L. Barth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812149/s-l-barth) is on the right track, but isn't quite there. What you need to do is to go through the cartesian product of both lists, compare the `y` parts and if they match, then you can emit a tuple on the output.

This can easily be done with a [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension), such as this one:

```
[(x, z) | (x, y1) <- a, (y2, z) <- b, y1 == y2]
```

You should be able to wrap this in a function.

Note that if you want the function to be polymorphic, the type of it needs an `Eq y` constraint so that you can actually compare the `y` parts:

```
composite :: Eq y => [(x, y)] -> [(y, z)] -> [(x, z)]
```

Comment: Ah yes, `Eq`. Good for you to think of that. Voting up.